# Resize Bytes[] Of image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a byte array [], is an image the byte array, is there a way to change the size of the image, but by directly transforming the byte array?

Comment: You'll need more detail to get a real answer.  This is tagged with unity3d, does that mean the "image" you have is a `Texture2D` object you're trying to manipulate?  Do you have a reference to a `UnityEngine.UI.Image` and you need to work with that?  Also, in C#, arrays are a fixed size; if you want to resize one you must create a new array of the size you'd like and then use that new array.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format ot bytes[]. if the image is a JPG or a PNG than no, you cannot change its size with direct transformation, you need to load it to a texture, blit and grab from rendertexture.

It the data is raw, than yes, its possible to resize, but unlikely to give good results. You can create a new array and copy values at points corresponding to your new coordinate (by nearest neighbour sampling or by implementing some sort of interpolation engine).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that changes the size and saves to disk for checking.
I wrote for example, you can improve.

```
public class Resize : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    Sprite m_InSprite;
    [SerializeField]
    int width;
    [SerializeField]
    int height;

    [ContextMenu("RESIZE+++")]
    public void Test()
    {
        Texture2D tex = GetResizeText(m_InSprite.texture);
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\test.png", tex.EncodeToPNG());
    }
    public Texture2D GetResizeText(Texture2D oldTex)
    {
        Func<Texture2D, int, int, Color> convert = delegate (Texture2D tex, int X, int Y)
        {
            float scaleI = tex.width / (float)width;
            float scaleJ = tex.height / (float)height;
            int I = (int)(scaleI * X);
            int J = (int)(scaleJ * Y);
            scaleI = (scaleI < 1) ? 1 : scaleI;
            scaleJ = (scaleJ < 1) ? 1 : scaleJ;
            int lengthI = (int)scaleI + I;
            int lengthJ = (int)scaleJ + J;
            List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
            for (int i = I; i < lengthI; i++)
            {
                for (int j = J; j < lengthJ; j++)
                {
                    colors.Add(tex.GetPixel(i, j));
                }
            }
            //TO DO
            //here you need to find the median of the List colors, but I was too lazy
            int length = colors.Count;
            int m1 = length / 2;
            return colors[m1];
        };
        Texture2D texResize = new Texture2D(width, height);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                Color col = convert(oldTex, x, y);
                texResize.SetPixel(x, y, col);
            }
        }
        return texResize;
    }
}
```